# Laravel 5.4 - How to paginate eager loading relationships

Tags: laravel, pagination, relationship, eager-loading

I have the following code to retrieve a given section's threads along with its comments along with its likes. It works but I want to paginate the results.

```
return $this->threads()->where('state', '=', 'active')->with('comments.likes')->get();
```

One way is to do this, but it results in a ton of queries as it doesn't eager load.

```
return $this->threads()->where('state', '=', active)->paginate(5);
```

Is there any way I can eager load all the data and also take advantage of Laravel's pagination magic?

Comment: So , If You want to load all the data then .., What is the use of paginate ..

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar When I said all the data I meant the relationship data.

Comment: okkkk..........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can paginate threads like this:

```
Thread::where('section_id', $sectionId)
      ->where('state', 'active')
      ->with('comments.likes')
      ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Perfect! I also found out it works like this: `return $this->threads()->where('state', '=', 'active')->with('comments.likes')->paginate(5);`. I tried it before but was getting errors so I must have messed something up. Thank you.